# val and fadeOut not working on click

Tags: javascript, jquery

i'm creating a ajax post request that works fine. however to make it more appealing i'm trying to implement so that when the user click on `#sign_in` it will change the text while request is going on. if it result in error a message will appear. this message will automatically remove after a couple of seconds. however if u click `.close` it will force close. The issue is however that following does not work:

```
$(".alert a").click(function(e) {
    $('.alert').fadeOut();
});
```

Nothing happens when i click on `.close`. in addition to this below does not work either.

```
$('#sign_in').val('Logger ind...');
```

**Full Code**

```
<form id="sign_in">
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" name="username" id="username" class="form-control" placeholder="Email">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="password" name="password" id="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Kodeord">
        </div>
        <a href="#">
            <small>Forgot password?</small>
        </a>
        <div class="form-group text-center add_top_20">
            <input class="btn_1 medium" id="sign_in" type="submit" value="Log ind">
            <input type="hidden" name="next" value="{{ next }}" />
        </div>
</form>

<div class="alert alert-error alert-danger" style="display: none;">
    <a class="close" href="#">×</a>
    Invalid email or password. Try clicking 'Forgot Password' if you're having trouble signing in.
</div>
```

**jquery**

```
$("#sign_in").submit(function (event) {
    // Change sign in button text
    $('#sign_in').val('Logger ind...');

    // post request
    event.preventDefault();
    var username = $('#username').val();
    var password = $('#password').val();
    $.ajax({
        url: "/account/login/auth/",
        type: "POST",
        dataType : 'json',
        contentType: 'application/json',
        data: {
            'username': username,
            'password': password
        }, success: function (data) {

            if (data.success) {
                alert('success');
            } else {
                showAlert()
            }
            // Change sign in text back
            $('#sign_in').val('Log ind');
        }, error: function(error){
            // Change sign in text back
            $('#sign_in').val('Log ind');
        }
    });
});

function showAlert(){
    if(!$('.alert').is(':visible'))
    {
        $('.alert').fadeIn()
        $('.alert').delay(4000).fadeOut()
    }
}
$(".alert a").click(function(e) {
    $('.alert').fadeOut();
});
```

and all of this is wrapped in `$(document).ready(function () {`

Comment: you must use unique id in all html tags, your _form tag_ and _input tag_ with same id **sign_in**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mmm, your event is launching but you need to use clearQueue in order to launch your fadeOut animation again interrupting the previous one.

```
$(".alert a").click(function(e) {
   $('.alert').clearQueue();
   $('.alert').fadeOut();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your form `id` or submit button `id` and change `:visible` to `:hidden`

```
function showAlert(){
        if($('.alert').is(':hidden'))
        {
            $('.alert').fadeIn()
            $('.alert').delay(4000).fadeOut()
        }
    }
```

Here I have change form 'id'

```
<form id="sign_in_form">
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" name="username" id="username" class="form-control" placeholder="Email">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="password" name="password" id="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Kodeord">
        </div>
        <a href="#">
            <small>Forgot password?</small>
        </a>
        <div class="form-group text-center add_top_20">
            <input class="btn_1 medium" id="sign_in" type="submit" value="Log ind">
            <input type="hidden" name="next" value="{{ next }}" />
        </div>
</form>

<div class="alert alert-error alert-danger" style="display: none;">
    <a class="close" href="#">×</a>
    Invalid email or password. Try clicking 'Forgot Password' if you're having trouble signing in.
</div>
```

jQuery

```
$("#sign_in_form").submit(function (event) {
    // Change sign in button text
    $('#sign_in').val('Logger ind...');

    // post request
    event.preventDefault();
    var username = $('#username').val();
    var password = $('#password').val();
    $.ajax({
        url: "/account/login/auth/",
        type: "POST",
        dataType : 'json',
        contentType: 'application/json',
        data: {
            'username': username,
            'password': password
        }, success: function (data) {

            if (data.success) {
                alert('success');
            } else {
                showAlert()
            }
            // Change sign in text back
            $('#sign_in').val('Log ind');
        }, error: function(error){
            // Change sign in text back
            $('#sign_in').val('Log ind');
        }
    });
});

function showAlert(){
    if($('.alert').is(':hidden'))
    {
        $('.alert').fadeIn()
        $('.alert').delay(4000).fadeOut()
    }
}
$(".alert a").click(function(e) {
    $('.alert').clearQueue();
    $('.alert').fadeOut();
});
```